# Что означает "@" в вызове сниппета?

Tags: modx

Что означает "@" в вызове сниппета `[[!getPage@...]]`?

Answer (score 2):

Это набор параметров.

К примеру, чтобы каждый раз не прописывать

```
[[!getPage? &blabla=`20` &tutu=`name`]]
```

ты в настройках сниппета задаешь параметры, называешь их, например, qwerty.

И чтобы их применить, просто пишешь

```
[[!getPage@qwerty]]
```